# MOD_REWRITE conditional redirection

Tags: php, apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I've an issue using Apache Mod_Rewrite module,

I'm retrieving three variable from a get request say

```
$country
$state
$location
```

I'm successful in rewriting the url locally 
for example the url

```
localhost/directory/country/state/location /*is redirected to*/
localhost/directory/result.php?c=country&s=state&l=location
```

what I want to do is that I want to redirect

```
localhost/directory/country to localhost/directory/country.php?c=country
```

and in case of

```
localhost/directory/country/state to localhost/directory/state.php?c=country&s=state
```

I'm using following RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ result.php?s=$1&d=$2&l=$3 [L]
```

how can I rewrite incase of country and state, and in case if I want to display only country page..

thanks a lot!!
please help me out, by giving references to online tutorials and other references..

I would be highly obliged to you to for the same.. :)

Comment: Duplicate that rule with fewer placeholders and with your other / shortened replacement urls/params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a downward flow in order to recognize if the URL is a country, state, or location
 with something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Rewrite Engine On
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/result.php?c=$1&s=$2&l=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/state.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/country.php?c=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Notice how I have started with the longest, the most dynamic URL, first. If you started with the shortest first, in your case `country`, then the URL_Rewrite would accept that `answer` first, and you would never hit the other two Rewrites.

Although I find it easier on the PHP parsing side to handle all dynamic URL traffic on one php page, on your case something like `result.php` that way you can determine the output, and you don't have to worry about jumping around on files.

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Rewrite Engine On
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/result.php?c=$1&s=$2&l=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/result.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^localhost/directory/([^/\.]+)/ localhost/directory/result.php?c=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`result.php`

```
<?php
$location = isset($_GET['l']) ? $_GET['l'] : false;
$state    = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : false;
$country  = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : false;

// ...PARSE THE REST OF PHP based off of these variables
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @samuel. I will surely utilize the on file variable parsing concept you suggested... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use two rules:

```
# localhost/directory/country
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)$  localhost/directory/country.php?c=$1 [L]

# localhost/directory/country/state
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  localhost/directory/state.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]
```